# can I format member profiles?

Tags: members, profile

can I format a profile in the bio section of a member profile without resorting to html tags? We often need to use **bold**, *italic* and especially links.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is a plain text field in the database, and it is rendered as plain text in the control panel.

Comment: Alas. That's what I thought. I was hoping that there was an add-on, etc. Much appreciated.

Comment: Mark me up 1 Answer for those that search again, Michael?